# Change of Variables to compute integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \int e^{xy} dx dy $   over a region $S$ where $S$ is in the first quadrant. $x>0, y>0$ of the $xy$ plane bounded by the curves  $ xy=1, xy=4$  and the line $  y=x, y=e^{2}x$

This is a HW question I have been given for a advanced Calculus class but I am not sure how to go about solving it.

Update: Iam planning to set $u =xy$ so that $1 < u < 4$ but I am not sure what range to choose for v should it be   $0 < v < e^2$

Comment: The best thing you can do is draw an accurate picture of the region $S$.

Comment: If you are doing the same problem I'm doing I think you should clarify that the one boundary is not y=e^(2x) but rather y=(e^2)x. Think about how to put these coordinates into another plane, maybe a u,v plane where the boundaries make a nice rectangle instead of some odd shape like it is now. For example if the limits were something like u=a to u=b and v=c to v=d where u and v were functions of x and y, and a,b,c,d were constants, you would have a really nice shape to integrate over.

Comment: thanks, I have made the change.I was having a hard time bcoz I had the question wrong myself. :) I will update what my final soln is toverify it withyou.

Comment: Iam planning to set u =xy so    1<u<4 but I am not sure what range to choose for v should it be   0<v<e^2

Comment: I'm assuming the ending of that was e^2 - x ?  That's close, you have the right idea.  When you arrange for your function v the range will be obvious.  

So you have u(x,y) = xy, good.  v(x,y) = ? so that you have constants as your boundaries?  Having those constants is important.  

Trying v(x,y) = y-x is really messy because of that e^2, but you do need to isolate a constant on one side of the equation, and x and y on the other as v(x,y).  

I'll give you a hint, the limits for v will be from 1 to e^2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plot of the region $S$:

[image]

If you integrate over $x$, there are 3 pieces to this region.  The first is between $y=e^{2 x}$ and $y=1/x$.  The second is between $y=4/x$ and $y=1/x$.  The third is between $y=4/x$ and $y=x$.  Where are the limits in $x$ for each piece?

Comment: Thanks for providing me with the graph this helps a lot. However, I am not sure what you mean when you ask "Where are the limits in x for each piece?" Do you mean the limit of y=e^2x, y=4/x, y=1/x, y=x.I will update what I have done so far but Math typing is new to me and its taking sometime for me to type Math.

Comment: I am asking you where the various curves intersect each other.  By looking at the plot, you can tell which intersections you need to solve.